# HTML Change button state permanenty

Tags: button, state, html

I am completely new to web development. The question I have is rather simple (I guess), but after multiple hours of using google and experimenting I am still without any solution. The problem I have is probably not how to do it, but which keywords to use while searching.

I want to create a simple website. (For testing I use Caddy Server). For my website I use a simple index.html file. On my website I want to have 9 buttons, which will be disabled once clicked. After refreshing the page, every client should also see the changes, so the button-state has to be stored somewhere on the server.

Then there will be another button, which sets the web page to its initial state (all buttons enabled). The purpose of this web page is that 2 persons can click buttons successivley until only one button is left enabled (the web page reloads itself every second on every client). This will be used to select a certain map from a map-pool of 9 maps.

**My main problem is**, to store the button states, so after refreshing the page the buttons should be still disabled if they were clicked. All clients should see the buttons as diabled once they refresh their pages. Do I have to implement a database for this or store the button states in xml or json? Do I need javascript, jquery, php or ajax for this? I do not want to make it very complicated, so if I need for example a database for this, I will probably just give up.

**What I'm asking for:** Any point in the right direction on how to implement a simple button that keeps its state after reloading the page would be much appreciated. I found a solution for this using JQuery, but it does not work for me (button does not preserve state after refreshing [See here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=559864&action=edit)).

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: "2 persons can click buttons successivley until only one button is left enabled" if X clicks the button it is disabled for Y? if yes you need a database. for just saving the state javascript+cookie is the right tool (by right i mean the simplest as you asked)

Comment: Cookies save the state of the button only for the user that clicked on the button, right? I need syncronisation between all users, so once a user disabled a button, this button should be disabled for all users that acess the website. If this really needs a database, I will not do it, since this small aplication is not worth such an effort. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is too broad a question as it stands. You will need some server-side technology (php etc). You could store the state in an Application Cache, the exact syntax will vary depending on the server-side technology  you use. You will no longer have "flat" html files. Also be aware that the application cache will refresh whenever the application refreshes due to server restarts etc. For anything more permanent, you will need a database or persistent data store.

Comment: The Application Cache would be fine for me, there is no need to store the values over a longer period of time, just some minutes at max. I will try to implement this in php now, now that I know that it is possible and php can be used for it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your server will need a data store (database) to save the values desired for each button.

#### Client Side

Set `disabled` attribute on all relevant buttons in your HTML. On (client-side) page load, fetch the value(s) from your server (database) and depending on what the returned value(s) are, `.clearAttribute("disabled")` on all buttons accordingly.

#### Server Side

Have your server set the `disabled` attribute on the HTML `<button>` elements based on values in your database prior to serving the HTML to your client(s).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had something similiar in mind, I was just hoping to find a simple solution without having to setup a database. In the comments above someone mentioned a solution that might help me. Thanks anyways for taking the time for me!

Comment: If the `disabled` state of your buttons depends on other users actions, you must have a data store to record the actions of other users.